# OpenShift system and package updates/patches

Tags: openshift

How does one keep OpenShift gears up-to-date? For example, updates to:

1. The Linux kernel
2. Important components/libraries like libc
3. Apache
4. Apache modules like mod_wsgi
5. Python
6. Python packages

Does OpenShift automatically update these and then restart the gear (or reboot the node)? Or does OpenShift send email notifications and the end-user can restart the gear during maintenance windows? What is the model?

What got me thinking about this was back in January there was a [remote-code-execution bug in Ruby on Rails](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2013-0153.html) that everyone had to patch immediately.

This [FAQ](https://www.openshift.com/faq/will-an-openshift-online-upgrade-cause-downtime-on-my-app-if-so-is-there-a-way-to-avoid-it) seems to suggest that some level of upgrades happen automatically, but it isn’t clear whether this only applies to the OpenShift-specific code, or also other components like the kernel, Apache, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you from my experience that changes to the openshift system are not always automatic. They had a change about 10 days ago and I'm still tracking down what they did to make my app run correctly. As far as I know there was no email sent.  I did find a blog post of some of the major changes, not all. Of course, they introduced at least one bug that I know of. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

My experiences over the last few weeks have been the following:

Last week there seemed to be an unannounced reboot of the server. I detected this by logging from a custom action hook. I didn't receive any email about it and I didn't see any notice at https://twitter.com/openshift_ops or https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status.

This week, there was the Heartbleed OpenSSL vulnerability and it seems like some gears were restarted. I didn't receive any email about it, Twitter didn't show anything, but there was information on the status page.